# how to create custom selector with local state

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

I need to create a custom selector that accepts redux state and local state to produce the result. But I don't know how to.

app.tsx

```
const initialConfig = {
  storeType: {
    [StoreType.CHAIN_STORE]: false,
    [StoreType.PROSPECT]: false,
    [StoreType.UNKNOWN]: false,
    [StoreType.PRODUCT]: false
  },
  photo: {
    binding: false
  },
  store: {
    noUnit: false,
    checkFlag: false,
    newRepo: false,
    notAssociated: false,
    deletedAssociation: false
  },
  keyword: ''
};
//it's ui state (user's custom filter)
const copy: <T extends object>(source: T) => T = source =>
  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(source));
const [config, setConfig] = useState<Config>(copy(initialConfig));
const photos = copy(useSelector(photoWithUnitSelector).reduce(
    filterFun(config),
    []
  );
//each time render need to do a deep copy to ensure useSelector is not memorized.But it's a really perform issue.
photoWithUnitSelector = createSelector([A,B,C],(a,b,c)=>[...result])
//It is my selector that all data is from redux state.
filterFun = (config) => (prev,curr) => {
  return my_own_fun_to_get_filtered_photos(config, prev, curr)
}
```

All I want is `useSelector(selector(config),shallowEqual)`
(combine redux state and local state to get my result)
But I don't know how to write the selector function.
Can someone give me a guide?

Comment: what do you mean by `local state`?

Comment: It's the component state(not in redux)

Comment: maybe move local state into redux is good solution for you?

Comment: It's quite easy to do using [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) hook